# How to append a pandas Dataframe with a list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list which I get after performing `x=list(df.iloc[3])` the list which I get is

```
[u'some name',
 u'some product name',
 u'some url',
 u'Development',
 u'Web Development',
 u'MX2,250',
 14247,
 4160,
 nan]
```

I have to append this list into another dataframe named "new" with columns

```
Index(
    [u'Instructor Name', u'Product Name',
     u'Product Url', u'Category 1', u'Category 2',
     u'Price', u'Students Enrolled', u'Reviews', u'Stars'],
     dtype='object')
```

When I use `new.append(x,ignore_index=True)` I am getting a new column with the values of x in it which is not what I want. How to flatten the list so values of x can be appended with the new.

Answer (score 1):

append a series instead of a list like this

```
new.append(pd.Series(x, new.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

---

This also works but only if `new`'s index is ordered sequential integers.

```
new.loc[len(new), :] = x
```

Comment: `x` was always "flat" in that it is one dimensional.  It's how `pandas` handles the `append` with a list.  It thinks you are trying to append every element of the list as a separate row.  **And** it doesn't know what column its for so it assigns a new column `0` to accommodate the incoming values.  What I did is to be more explicit about what is being appended and provided pandas with relevant information to do what I want.